# jQuery .each through multiple elements after dom loaded

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get all the values from the elements such as input datepicker image and bio, into a multidimensional array, with a each loop

I am inputting 2 people to test it works.
This is the html for the values I am trying to get

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" >
    <button onclick="WIShowInstaller.newPerson()">Add Person</button>

    <ul class="list-group" id="person">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all showperson">
            <article class="post_container" id="PersonPost">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <label for="name" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                        <div class="showpersonnel">Name
                            <input type="text" name="personsName" id="personsName" placeholder="person's Name"></div>
                    </label>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <figure class="post-image" id="show_Image">            
                            <div id="dragandrophandler" class="dragandrophandler">Drag & Drop Files Here</div>
                            <div class="showpersonnel">Photo<div class="img-preview" id="preview-1"></div></div>
                            <div class="upload-msg" id="status"></div>
                       </figure>
                   </div>

                   <input type="hidden" name="supload" id="supload" class="supload" value="person">

                   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                       <div class="showpersonnel">Biography
                           <textarea type="text" class="bio" name="bio" id="bio" placeholder="Biography"></textarea>
                      </div>
                   </div>

                   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                       <div class="showpersonnel">D.O.B
                           <input type="text" name="dob" class="dob" id="datepicker-1" placeholder="Date of birth">
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </article>
       </li>
   </ul>
```

This is the jquery code to try and get multiple values and create a multidimensional array

```
WIShowInstaller.InstallPeople = function() {
    var name = $(".personsName").val();
    var textArea = $('textarea.bio');
    var bio = textArea.val();
    var dob = $(".dob").val();
    var img = $(".personImg").attr('value');

    alert(name);
    alert(bio);
    alert(dob);
    alert(img);  /// All the above prints out first set of 4 values only

    var person = [];
    var a = 0;

    $("li.showperson").each(function(i) {
        person[a] = {};

        $(this).find('.showpersonnel').each(function() {
            var title = $(this).text();
            var value = $(this).next(':input').val();
            person[a][title] = value;
        });

        a++;
    });

    console.log(person); /// prints out undefined
}
```

print out from console.log

```
     Array(2)
           [0]
               "Biography↵ ↵ ":undefined
               "D.O.B↵ ": undefined
               "Name↵ ": undefined
               "Photo": undefined
           [1]
               "Biography":undefined
               "D.O.B":undefined
               "Name": undefined
               "Photo":undefined
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do? What is the problem you face when trying? and the expected result. That would help us understand your scenario and in consequence to yourself

Comment: Re edited it, to add the code properly, I think I have been wake too long to think straight lol

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote my answer to take into account that there may be several personal data

```js
const people = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.person')).map(person => {
      const obj = {};

      const dataset = Array.from(person.children);

      dataset.forEach(data => {
          switch (data.className) {
              case 'personName':
                  obj.Name = data.value;
                  break;
              case 'bio':
                  obj.Biography = data.value;
                  break
              case 'dop':
                  obj['D.O.B'] = data.value;
                  break
              case 'personImg':
                  obj.Photo = data.value;
                  break
          }
      });

      return obj;
  });

  console.log(people);
```

```html
<div class="person">
    <input class="personName" value="alicia">
    <textarea class="bio">nami</textarea>
    <input class="dop" value="goku">
    <input class="personImg" value="krilin">
</div>

<div class="person">
    <input class="personName" value="ken">
    <textarea class="bio">nami</textarea>
    <input class="dop" value="goku">
    <input class="personImg" value="krilin">
</div>

<div class="person">
    <input class="personName" value="usop">
    <textarea class="bio">nami</textarea>
    <input class="dop" value="zoro">
    <input class="personImg" value="sanji">
</div>
```

Take into account that I do not duplicate your html because it is saturated. I'm sure you can adapt the logic

Comment: Thank you, that is the sort thing I am looking for,  its not perfect, but I a getting the values of the bios but its more than I was getting before, I should be able to work with that to be able to get the rest, just dont want to sleep till its working
<code>(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{img-responsive personImg: undefined}
1
:
{bio: "jay amn"}
2
:
{img-responsive personImg: undefined}
3
:
{bio: "book"}</code>

Comment: I rewrote my answer to take into account that there may be several personal data

Comment: Thank you so much, that is awesome, and works like a charm, now I have saved it, I can play around with it somewhat, I do not see any buttons, to be able to like this answer or a thumbs up etc, but I really appreciate your time, and effect

Comment: No problem. Jules. When possible hit the accepted answer button

Comment: upped for saturated comment.